# How to check if a class depends on CDI for creating an instance?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

How to check if a class needs CDI injection to create an instance?

For example,

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    private Bar bar;

    // constructor/setter method can have @Inject
}
```

If a class depends on CDI but CDI is not available, no instances should be created. Is there a standard CDI api to check if a class depends on CDI?

The use case is that user can register listener classes. If a listener class depend on CDI but CDI is not available, the listener will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your question shortly, but part of the point of dependency injection is that the annotations (such as `@Inject`) shouldn't impact class design.

If you have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
  private final Bar bar;
  @Inject
  public Foo(final Bar bar) {
    super();
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

…then whether *you* create a `Foo` or *CDI* creates a `Foo` makes no difference to how the `Foo` is created.  The same APIs (the same constructor) are used in both cases.

Things of course get a little weirder when you talk about `private` field injection, like this:

```
public class Foo {
  @Inject
  private Bar bar;
  public Foo() {
    super();
  }
}
```

That is a class where (as written) it is impossible to create it without doing reflection tricks.  That, of course, is exactly what a CDI implementation does.

So all of that to say that I'm guessing that you're asking something else.  I just am not sure what that is.

To answer your question as you've asked it:

One way of determining whether a given CDI implementation "knows about" a given class is to do something mildly awful like this:

```
final Instance<YourClass> yourClassInstances = CDI.current().select(YourClass.class);
if (yourClassInstances.isUnsatisified()) {
  // CDI for whatever reason can't create a YourClass instance; maybe this is
  // sort of what you want?
} else {
  // CDI "knows about" your class; actually trying to get an instance might
  // result in ambiguity
}
```

Comment: Updated questions: 
The use case is that user can register listener classes. If a listener class depend on CDI but CDI is not available, the listener will be ignored. But your code requires CDI provider in classpath.

Comment: Hmm; a different question.  The answer to this question is: write a portable extension that processes observer methods.  It will be invoked if CDI is available and won't if it is not.

Comment: When CDI is not available, still need to check if a listener class depends on CDI. Ignore it or instantiate an instance by calling default constructor.